# Multiple Buttons/Objects on the same row

Tags: android, android-layout, positioning, android-button

I want to have `Buttons` next to each other on the same line, and I want to have one `Button` next to an `EditText`.

I have the Eclipse addon, so I have both the graphical layout, as well as the text. I can't post an image, but I'll describe it: *it has two `TextViews` (irrelevant), followed by an `EditText`, and then a small unlabeled `Button` on the next line. The next four lines are buttons labeled Turn N, Turn E, Turn S, and Turn W.*

So, next to that `EditText` is where I want the untitled `Button` to be, and I want the N, E, S, W `Buttons` to be setup in a compass-like fashion. However, when I try to drag them on the GUI, it binds them to the row, and whenever I try to change the layout, it affects everything, rather than only the one object I'm right-clicking.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button4"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful, and now my graphical layout view of the XML is displaying it just as I want it to. (I added a few more buttons as well), however, now in my Java file, there are errors on everything that references main. Under "setContentView(R.layout.main);" it says error: "main cannot be resolved or is not a field." My xml file does not display any errors, and I've tried restarting eclipse, I can't find anything wrong with it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @Zeldarulah Try to clean your project(In menu `Project-> Clean`) and also check if you imported the correct `R` class(with `CTRL + SHIFT + O`) from your package(and NOT `import android.R;`).

Comment: I do have "import android.R;", but I tried both Project -> Clean and CTRL + Shift + O, and it did not change it. Should "import android.R;" be something different? Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeldarulah That line `import android.R;` hides your project generated `R` class and android doesn't find the layout, ids. Delete that line and you should be Ok. (if you use some part of the `android.R` namespace then don't import the `import android.R;` and simply use `android.R.something` where you need)

Comment: Well, that fixed it! Thanks a ton. I'm not quite sure why that import was causing a problem, but thanks a ton. If I could upvote your answer, I would, but my rep is still too low.

Comment: @Zeldarulah The `android.R` class hides your project `R` class, when android builds your app it tries to find the ids and layouts in the only `R` class that it sees(but of course they aren't there). If I helped, you could mark my answer as correct with the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really say about it without xml, but if you want to position buttons in compas-like fashion, you should try to create quadrate relative layout, put buttons to it, and then position buttons at top, left, right and bottom of the parent